# How to locate a variable throughout the whole project in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

I have a C++ Visual Studio project, in which I wish to locate one particular constant throughout the whole project. That is, I want to locate that particular variable in every single file in my project, including all `.cpp` and `.h`.

[A previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9435642/how-to-get-visual-studio-2010-to-highlight-instances-of-a-variable) seems to be relevant, but it is only able to locate the variable within **ONE file**.

How may I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **Quick Find** available on the **Edit** ► **Find and Replace** ► **Quick Find** menu. With my key bindings it is bound to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd>.

The **Quick Find** dialog box is shown in the upper right corner of the editor window. You can change where to search from the drop down. Normally you search in **Current Document** but you can change it to **Entire Solution**.

[image: Quick Find]

If you want to search `.h` files that are not part of your solution you can use **Find in Files** available on the **Edit** ► **Find and Replace** ► **Find in Files** menu. Here you can specify a scope that also includes files of a specific type in a folder.